# PHPStorm change highlighting level for Project

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm

Hello I´am maintaing quite large and old project in cakephp with PHPStorm and I have problem: When I open .ctp or .js file it starts freezing If i don´t set highlighting level to 0. I want to ask is there some option to set it for whole Project and save, that I do not need to set it again, when I reopen Project.

Comment: 1) Try disabling inspections -- most likely they are the reason and not actual syntax highlighting 2) Try `File | PoweSave mode`